# Finding difference in time between two data frames using R

Tags: r

I have two data frame ,one is the in time of employees and the other is the out time of employees.The data in both the data frames have timestamps for about 4000 employees in the last one year(excludes weekend/public holiday dates).Each data frame has 4000 rows and 250 columns.I would like to find the number of hours spent by an employee each day at work basically my approach would be to find the difference in time between the two data frames using difftime() function.i used the below code and expected a resulting data frame containing 4000 rows and 250 columns with difference in time,however the data was returned in one single column.How should I deal with this problem so that I can get the difference in time between two data frames in the data frame format with 4000 rows and 250 columns?

```
hours_spent <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(difftime(as.matrix(out_time_data_hrs),as.matrix(in_time_data_hrs),unit='hour')))
```

Input data looks like below ,

In_time data frame

[image]

Out_time data frame

[image]

Expected output

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please share output of  `dput(intime_df)` and `dput(outtime_df)` in the question description. It will be helpful then to try out some code on the objects. Just take a subset of both the matrices in the `dput` function.

Comment: You want to apply a logic (hours spent) to each employee and each day. You should probably need to reshape your dataset to something more "tidy". Imagine something like columns `employee id`, `day`, `in_time`, `out_time`, You'll make it easier for yourself to see which columns you have to `group_by` and which columns to use for your calculation.

Comment: You haven't provided an ideal output, but I'll post an example based on what you've showed so far that I hope helps you understand the logic and apply it to your case.....

Comment: added desired output

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small and simple example based on the data you posted and a possible solution:

```
# example data in_times
df1 = data.frame(`2018-08-01` = c("2018-08-01 10:30:00", "2018-08-01 10:25:00"),
                 `2018-08-02` = c("2018-08-02 10:20:00", "2018-08-02 10:45:00"))
# example data out_times
df2 = data.frame(`2018-08-01` = c("2018-08-01 17:33:00", "2018-08-01 18:06:00"),
                 `2018-08-02` = c("2018-08-02 17:11:00", "2018-08-02 17:45:00"))

library(tidyverse)

# reshape datasets
df1_resh = df1 %>%
  mutate(empl_id = row_number()) %>%   # add an employee id (using the row number)
  gather(day, in_time, -empl_id)       # reshape dataset

df2_resh = df2 %>%
  mutate(empl_id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(day, out_time, -empl_id)

# join datasets and calculate hours spent
left_join(df1_resh, df2_resh, by=c("empl_id","day")) %>%
  mutate(hours_spent = difftime(out_time, in_time))

#   empl_id         day             in_time            out_time    hours_spent
# 1       1 X2018.08.01 2018-08-01 10:30:00 2018-08-01 17:33:00 7.050000 hours
# 2       2 X2018.08.01 2018-08-01 10:25:00 2018-08-01 18:06:00 7.683333 hours
# 3       1 X2018.08.02 2018-08-02 10:20:00 2018-08-02 17:11:00 6.850000 hours
# 4       2 X2018.08.02 2018-08-02 10:45:00 2018-08-02 17:45:00 7.000000 hours
```

You can use this as the final piece of code if you want to reshape back to your initial format:

```
left_join(df1_resh, df2_resh, by=c("empl_id","day")) %>%
  mutate(hours_spent = difftime(out_time, in_time)) %>%
  select(empl_id, day, hours_spent) %>%
  spread(day, hours_spent)

#   empl_id    X2018.08.01 X2018.08.02
# 1       1 7.050000 hours  6.85 hours
# 2       2 7.683333 hours  7.00 hours
```

Comment: makes sense, will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

my requirement is satisfied by just doing the below, pretty straight forward

```
employee_hrs_df <- out_time_data - in_time_data
```