# I have two files which contains in_time and out_time values of the employess I need to find out the time in office how can I do that in R programming?

Tags: r

enter code here

```
in_time <- read.csv('in_time.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)
out_time <- read.csv('out_time.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)

 for(i in 2:length(colnames(in_time)) ) {
  in_time[i] <- strptime(in_time[i], format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
}

for(i in 2:length(colnames(out_time)) ) {  
  out_time[i] <- strptime(out_time[i], format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
}

#time_difference
for(i in 2:length(colnames(out_time)) ) {
time_in_office[i] <- out_time[i] - in_time[i]
}
```

I am not able to get the time difference both in_time and out_time files contains date time values except first column

Comment: What format do you have? You need to post some data. Maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917684/finding-difference-in-time-between-two-data-frames-using-r/51917886#51917886

Comment: they are in character format initially I'm converting into date format with for loop and then directly subtracting both  without merging them into                > head(in_time)
  EmployeeID      X02.01.2015      X05.01.2015      X06.01.2015      X07.01.2015
1          1 02-01-2015 09:43 05-01-2015 10:08 06-01-2015 09:54 07-01-2015 09:34
2          2 02-01-2015 10:15 05-01-2015 10:21   07-01-2015 09:45
3          3 02-01-2015 10:17 05-01-2015 09:50 06-01-2015 10:14

Comment: Please use the edit functionality and append any additional information to your original post.

Comment: After `read.csv` you have dataframes. There are commas missing, it should be `in_time[, i]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks AntoniosK,Rui,Roman, now I got them!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate` package to work calculate time differences of in- and out- events. To calculate time difference for in_time and out_time you can use `mapply` function. Please see the code below:

```
in_time <- structure(list(EmployeeID = 1:3, X02.01.2015 = c("02-01-2015 09:43", 
"02-01-2015 10:15", "02-01-2015 10:17"), X05.01.2015 = c("05-01-2015 10:08", 
"05-01-2015 10:21", "05-01-2015 09:50"), X06.01.2015 = c("06-01-2015 09:54", 
"07-01-2015 09:45", "06-01-2015 10:14"), X07.01.2015 = c("07-01-2015 09:34", 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

out_time <- structure(list(EmployeeID = c(1, 2, 3), X02.01.2015 = c("02-01-2015 19:43", 
"02-01-2015 18:15", "02-01-2015 17:17"), X05.01.2015 = c("05-01-2015 15:02", 
"05-01-2015 12:11", "05-01-2015 21:50"), X06.01.2015 = c("06-01-2015 16:34", 
"07-01-2015 19:45", "06-01-2015 18:14"), X07.01.2015 = c("07-01-2015 21:34", 
"NA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

library(lubridate)
# converse date\time into POSIXct format
in_time[, -1] <- lapply(in_time[, -1], dmy_hm)
out_time[, -1] <- lapply(out_time[, -1], dmy_hm)

# calculate time difference
result <- in_time
result[, -1] <- mapply(function(x, y) {
  mapply(function(x, y) as.numeric(as.period(interval(x, y)), unit = "hours"), x, y)
}, in_time[,-1], out_time[,-1])

result
```

Output: amount of time an employee spent at work, in hours:

```
  EmployeeID X02.01.2015 X05.01.2015 X06.01.2015 X07.01.2015
1          1          10    4.900000    6.666667          12
2          2           8    1.833333   10.000000          NA
3          3           7   12.000000    8.000000          NA
```